# Can't find the LEGO set number for this item, black car with clear light blue canopy and front wheels?

Tags: set-identification, instructions

[image]

What LEGO set number is this item?

I just want to rebuild it after buy buying many boxes LEGO.

Answer (score 1):

This vehicle is missing some pieces, but comes from set [70162 Infearno Interception](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70162-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) from the Ultra Agents series. It came out in 2014.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's from set [70162 Inferno Interception](https://brickset.com/sets/70162-1/Infearno-Interception).

[image]

Here are the instructions that you're looking for:

http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/6093658.pdf